# Validate start-dfs.sh

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, cluster, hadoop, distributed-filesystem

I am trying to setup a Hadoop cluster, where master is my laptop and slave is the virtualbox, following this [guide](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/install-a-multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04/). So, I did, from *master*:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [master]
root@master's password: 
master: namenode running as process 2911. Stop it first.
root@master's password: root@slave-1's password: 
master: datanode running as process 3057. Stop it first.
<I gave password again here>

slave-1: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoopuser/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-gsamaras-VirtualBox.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
root@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 3234. Stop it first.
gsamaras@gsamaras:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin$ su - hadoopuser
Password: 
-su: /home/hduser/hadoop/sbin: No such file or directory
hadoopuser@gsamaras:~$ jps
15845 Jps
```

And the guide states:
"The output of this command should list NameNode, SecondaryNameNode, DataNode on master node, and DataNode on all slave nodes.", which doesn't seem to be the case here (*does it?*) and then I checked the *slave*'s log:

```
cat hadoop-root-datanode-gsamaras-VirtualBox.log
..rver: master/192.168.1.2:54310. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-01-24 02:42:14,160 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: master/192.168.1.2:54310

gsamaras@gsamaras-VirtualBox:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/logs$ ssh master
gsamaras@master's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3..
```

The logs in the master node seem error-less. Notice that I can do a password-less ssh from master to slave, but not vice versa, the guide doesn't mention something like this. Any ideas *please*?

---

When I execute `stop-dfs.sh`, I am getting the erroneous message:

```
slave-1: no datanode to stop
```

---

Now, I did it again and I got in the *master*:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./stop-dfs.sh
Stopping namenodes on [master]
root@master's password: 
master: no namenode to stop
root@master's password: root@slave-1's password: 
master: no datanode to stop   
slave-1: stopping datanode
Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
root@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: stopping secondarynamenode
gsamaras@gsamaras:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin$ jps
19048 Jps
gsamaras@gsamaras:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin$ ps axww | grep hadoop
19277 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto hadoop
gsamaras@gsamaras:/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/sbin$ jps
19278 Jps
```

and `ps axww | grep hadoop` in the *slave*, gave process with id 2553.

Comment: Does any of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18286887 help?

Comment: Thansk @JeffSchaller, since I am super-stuck, I updated my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set permissions not only in the hadoop-data foler as I thought, but in the hadoop folder itself:

```
sudo chown -R hadoopuser /home/hadoopuser/hadoop/
```

I got the idea from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37786/permission-denied-errors-whe-starting-a-single-node-cluster-in-hadoop).